# delete entire row from df based on the counting of the column's value

Tags: python, pandas, count, delete-row, distinct-values

I have the following df:

```
d = {'animal': ['lion', 'dog', 'cat', 'lion', 'shark', 'cat', 'lion', 'shark'], 'age': [3, 4, 9, 10, 8, 5, 8, 9]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

My goal is:

[image]

In other words, remove the entire row from df if the value from the 'animal' column repeats 3 times or more. In this case: (lion:3, shark:2, cat:2, dog:1) -- lion removed

How do I approach this problem? I'm iterating but I'm stuck. Is there any series method? How to approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
m=df_1['animal'].value_counts().ge(3)
#create a condition to check if the count of particular value is greater then or eq to 3 or not
```

Finally:

```
out=df_1[~df_1['animal'].isin(m[m].index)]
#Finally Filter out result
```

Output of `out`:

```
    animal  age
1   dog     4
2   cat     9
4   shark   8
5   cat     5
7   shark   9
```

If needed use `reset_index()` method:

```
out=out.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I didn´t know about "ge, le, gt", etc ! it also was extreamly helpful! thanks Anurag!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `count` and apply boolean masking.

```
m = df_1.groupby('animal')['animal'].transform('count').lt(3)
print(df_1[m])

  animal  age
1    dog    4
2    cat    9
4  shark    8
5    cat    5
7  shark    9
```